# Kotlin- Function runs after next lines ended

Tags: android, function, android-activity, kotlin, buttonclick

Updated- The code in the question works now

I'm trying to run a function after clicking on a button. The function updates an array and I want to run the next lines (The next lines transfer me to another activity) if the array isn't empty.

I tried to open the new activity within the `filterPlaces` function but with no success, `startActivity` and `Intent` don't work.

This is the function that updates the array:

```
var places = ArrayList<Place>() //Global place array
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun filterPlaces(types: ArrayList<String>, foods: ArrayList<String>, maxPrice: Int, maxProximity: Int) {
        var typesList = types
        val foodList = foods
        if (types.isEmpty()) {
            typesList = arrayListOf("Restaurant", "Hangouts")
            if (foods.isEmpty()) {
                foodList.add("Pizza")
            }
        }
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("places").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                val typeMatches = document.data["Type"].toString() in typesList
                val foodMatches = document.data["Food"].toString() in foodList
                var price = 0
                when (document.data["Price"].toString()) {
                    "Very cheap" -> price = 0
                    "Cheap" -> price = 1
                    "Average" -> price = 2
                    "Far" -> price = 3
                    "Very far" -> price = 4
                }
                val priceMatches = price <= maxPrice
                var proximity = 0
                when (document.data["Proximity"].toString()) {
                    "Very close" -> proximity = 0
                    "Close" -> proximity = 1
                    "Far" -> proximity = 2
                    "Very far" -> proximity = 3
                }
                val proximityMatches = proximity <= maxProximity
                if (typeMatches and foodMatches and priceMatches and proximityMatches) {
                    val place = Place(
                        document.data["Place"].toString(),
                        document.data["Type"].toString(),
                        document.data["Food"].toString(),
                        document.data["Price"].toString(),
                        document.data["Proximity"].toString()
                    )
                    places.add(place)
                    Log.d("name", "Place added successfully")
                }
            }

            //Openning the results activity
            if (places.isNotEmpty()) {
                val i = Intent(this, RelevantPlaces::class.java)
                val b = Bundle()
                b.putParcelableArrayList("places", places)
                i.putExtra("bundle", b)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("name", "Error getting documents.")
            }
    }
```

This is the on click function:

```
fun onSortFilterClicked(view: View) {
        if (places.isEmpty()) filterPlaces(types, foods, priceRange.progress, proximityRange.progress)
    }
```

I want to run `filterPlaces` first, update the `places` array while I run it, and only than check if the array is still empty and if not open the new activity.
What actually happens is that it calls the `filterPlaces` but doesn't do it, instead it checks the `places` array (The `if condition` in the code) and only than goes into `filterPlaces` and run what's in it, resulted in me need to press twice on the button and only than the array has values.
I'm running this on Android Studio and I'm new at this Kotlin world and android developing in general.

Is there a solution for this? Either open the activity within the function or make the function run first?

Comment: `if (places.isEmpty())` -- actually you start an `Activity` only if the array IS empty which seems to contradict your stated requirement

Comment: Right, it was one of my attempts to solve the problem, updated the code.

Comment: please post the code for the `filterPlaces(...)` method

Comment: Posted the function.

Comment: it seems you run an asynchronous request, this is why the method itself returns instantly.  Your data is updated inside the success scope which begins here: `{ result -> .... ` so you might want to start your `Activity` in this scope as well, after all the data was added to the `places` array

Comment: OK, I'm trying to do so as I said, it tells me this is not defined in this context and because of that the intent doesn't work.

Comment: use `this@YourCurrentActivityName`, that's how you refer to an outer scope in Kotlin

Comment: tried ```val i = Intent(this@MainActivity::class.java, RelevantPlaces::class.java)``` and also tried ```val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, RelevantPlaces::class.java)```, both doesn't work

Comment: Solved it, I accidentally placed the function outside the ```MainActivity``` class, so now I moved it in and it works

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please consider accepting the answer if it did solve your problem.

Comment: It's not exactly what happen, I wrote what happen and how I fixed that, If you think you wrote that in more professional language I would love to mark it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is happening?*

An asynchronous request is made in `filterPlaces`, this is why the method itself returns immediately and passes control to the next code block.

*How to fix this?*

Move your code starting another `Activity` into the scope of your success listener. A better approach is to place this code into a separate method and just call it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Placed the `filterPlace` function outside the `Main Activity` class. Moved the function in the `Main Activity` class and it worked.

Comment: could you update the code in your question to reflect your latest working code?

Comment: I added the main activity class line

Comment: so you are not starting the new `Activity` from the `onSuccess` scope? If not, chances are that you are getting some cached result after the initial request since Firebase APIs are indeed [asynchronous](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Comment: If you say so I'll add the ```function``` to the ```onSuccess``` scope, updating the code now and deleting this answer

Comment: this looks fine to me

Comment: Thank you for all of you help!